# Polymer App Routing not picking up variables

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to pass variables in my urls using App Location and App Routing in Polymer, but the subroute doesn't seem to be picking up the variables. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
 <app-route
   route="{{route}}"
   pattern="/desk/:project/:scene"
   data="{{data}}"
   tail="{{subroute}}">
 </app-route>
```

The `route.path` is showing up as `/variable/variable`, but the `project` and `scene` are blank.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of `project` and `scene` are read from `data`, which is bound to `<app-route>.data` (as in `data.project` and `data.scene`).

So, if your URL were `http://localhost:8080/desk/123/456`, your `data` object would contain:

```
{
  project: '123',
  scene: '456'
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/EZamoG?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1):

The code below use two  elements to monitor the complete URL.
The first  will bind to the project value and output a {{subroute}} for the second element.

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
 <app-route
   route="{{route}}"
   pattern="/desk/:project"
   data="{{data}}"
   tail="{{subroute}}">
 </app-route>
```

The second  will bind to the scene value.

```
  <app-route
   route="{{subroute}}"
   pattern=":scene"
   data="{{data}}">
 </app-route>
```

Comment: I need the project variable as well.